# What is the Judgement in this case?

Tags: allah, fatwa-explanation

السلام عليكم
A guy was talking to a girl in the web , he wrote the لفظ الجلالة Allah in the page , is that Haram , or it is sort of mocking for the religion .,, ?

I searched the web for this , I saw in Islamweb which has question I asked before "they say that if someone was doing Haram , while the لفظ الجلالة was on the page , it's not mocking , but one should stop using this Haram thing , anyway , Another Fatwa says it is Haram to start something Haram with the name of Allah , but if someone for example was eating something , while watching Haram , and he said " In the name of Allah "for eating , that's totally different and they say that it is not even Haram to say.

Comment: At the first place, who said that it's haraam for a guy and a girl to talk on the web? If any, that's subject to many conditions.

Answer (score -1):

Assalamuelikum,

Well praising Allah on one side and doing something not liked by Allah on other side is sheer hypocrisy and disrepect for Allah. Regarding hypocrites Allah says in the Quran

> "**O Prophet! strive hard against the Unbelievers and the Hypocrites, and be firm against them. Their abode is Hell,- an evil refuge indeed.  (The Noble Quran, 9:73)**"

So you cannot justify haram on one side and halal one the other.